# Best Travel time Algorithm (Codewars) passing some tests. Python

Tags: python, algorithm

I apologize if I did not word my question properly but I am solving a code wars algorithm that states this: John and Mary want to travel between a few towns A, B, C ... Mary has on a sheet of paper a list of distances between these towns. ls = [50, 55, 57, 58, 60]. John is tired of driving and he says to Mary that he doesn't want to drive more than t = 174 miles and he will visit only 3 towns.

Example:

With list ls and 3 towns to visit they can make a choice between: [50,55,57],[50,55,58],[50,55,60],[50,57,58],[50,57,60],[50,58,60],[55,57,58],[55,57,60],[55,58,60],[57,58,60].

The sums of distances are then: 162, 163, 165, 165, 167, 168, 170, 172, 173, 175.

The biggest possible sum taking a limit of 174 into account is then 173 and the distances of the 3 corresponding towns is [55, 58, 60].

The function chooseBestSum (or choose_best_sum or ... depending on the language) will take as parameters t (maximum sum of distances, integer >= 0), k (number of towns to visit, k >= 1) and ls (list of distances, all distances are positive or null integers and this list has at least one element). The function returns the "best" sum ie the biggest possible sum of k distances less than or equal to the given limit t, if that sum exists, or otherwise nil, null, None, Nothing, depending on the language. With C++, C, Rust, Swift, Go, Kotlin return -1.

Examples:

ts = [50, 55, 56, 57, 58] choose_best_sum(163, 3, ts) -> 163

xs = [50] choose_best_sum(163, 3, xs) -> nil (or null or ... or -1 (C++, C, Rust, Swift, Go)

ys = [91, 74, 73, 85, 73, 81, 87] choose_best_sum(230, 3, ys) -> 228

---

This is the code I have written thus far that only has 2/3 test cases passing. For one test case, choose_best_sum(230, 4, xs), it should return 230 but my code is returning 226. I am not sure why.
These test cases work for this list: xs = [100, 76, 56, 44, 89, 73, 68, 56, 64, 123, 2333, 144, 50, 132, 123, 34, 89]

choose_best_sum(430, 5, xs), 430)
choose_best_sum(430, 8, xs), None)

```
def choose_best_sum(t, k, ls):
    most = 0

    for i in range(len(ls)-1):
        addN = 0
        if i +k > len(ls) - 1:
            break
        for j in range(i,i+k-1):
            addN += ls[j]
        for p in range(i+k-1,len(ls)-1):
            addN += ls[p]
            if addN > most and addN <= t:
                most = addN
                addN -= ls[p]
            else:
                addN -= ls[p]
    if most == 0:
        return None
    return most
```

What can I be doing wrong? I have gone step by step. I am unsure. Thank you.

Comment: How have you gone step by step? What does your code do? What is the idea behind it?

Comment: Yes, the code adds the integers up to k, and the next for loop iterates from k all the way down the end of the list each time adding and checking if it is greater than the most but less than or equal to the target. If it is not then we minus and iterate to the next ending.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that you only check *k* cities where the first *k-1* are next to each other. You only allow the last of those *k* cities (`p`) to be separated from the others, which remain adjacent in the range `i:i+k-1`. You really need a different approach all together.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I see. I will try a new approach thank you.